# where i am going wrong on my system the program is running correctly but getting wrong answer on submittionhttp://www.spoj.com/problems/NITT2/

Tags: c++

this is my code where i have tries to solve the problem but getting wrong answer on submission

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {

        long long int n;
        cin>>n;
        if(n%252==0)
            cout<<"Yes ";
        else
            cout<<"No ";

        if(n%525==0)
            cout<<"Yes";
        else
            cout<<"No";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong on my system the program is running correctly but getting wrong answer on submition [NITT2](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NITT2/) please help me where i am going wrong ...

Comment: wrong answers !!! like what?

Comment: If it is like other online judges it doesn't tell you what the wrong answer is, just that it is wrong.  You don't have access to the test data they use to judge.

Comment: Your fundamental error is that you don't check the result of performing the I/O operation.

Comment: @KerrekSB can you please explain it further...

Comment: @OMerObaid dont know about it

Answer (score 2):

You missed one of the problem statements:

`Each line contains one number N, whose divisibility is to be tested. 1 <= N <= 10^50000`

Specificly `1 <= N <= 10^50000`

You are reading the line into an `int`; it is an understatement that `int`'s storage is too small.  You have a couple of options.  You could use some kind of data type that can store at least 10^50000 and support the division operations. Another alternative is to find a better way to test the divisible condition directly against the string of data in some clever manner.

Comment: i tried it with long long int but then also getting  wrong answer can you please help me what data type to use then...

Comment: You would need at least a 170 bit data type. A long long int probably only gives you 63bit of storage for positive integers.  My answer still applies to why your code won't work on the judge server.

Comment: you mean i should string for taking input data

Comment: @codingisfun 10^50000 has 50,001 digits in decimal. In binary it would require almost 170,000 bits. That's quite a bit more than `long long int` will hold.

Comment: @molbdnilo so what data type i should use??should i use string??

Comment: @codingisfun You could probably look up "arbitrary precision arithmetic" and take it from there. Or use a language with built-in support. Also, you can use maths to rule out many impossible candidates (e.g. anything that ends with 3,7, or 9 is divisible by neither).

Comment: @molbdnilo i could try it in java using big integer class that solves my problem but the thing is i want to do it with c++.so what should i do for solving the question in c++ ??

Comment: @codingisfun *Write* a big integer implementation, perhaps? It may seem far-fetched to write code in order to solve a programming problem, but it's a really good way.

Comment: @molbdnilo i have solved it through big integer in java and that got accepted but now i am trying in c++.i just want to improve my single programming langauage that is c++.